# Query across multiple indexes, favoring duplicate document matches based on index (or criteria?)

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming the following criteria:

1. There are 2 indexes: `master-index` and `customer-index`
2. There is an alias for these 2 indexes: `customer-alias`
3. Any document in the `customer-index` is a copy of a document from the `master-index` with selected field values modified.

The analogy is a document revision system, where the initial document in the `master-index` is the *original* document. If a customer modifies a field in that document, the document is copied (via `_reindex`) to the `customer-index` with the field modifications PLUS a new field is added, such as `is_edited = true`.

This implies that the document in the `master-index` will have the same `_id` as the document in the `customer-index`.

Normal querying may match this customer modified document and the master document, but in the case of this duplication, I would only like the modified document.

Note: I do not want to limit my query to ONLY duplicates, but if duplicates exist, I ONLY want to return the duplicate document in the customer index.

In other words, for duplicates matched in the query (same `_id` from different index), dedupe or filter only to the document from the `customer-index`.

I've tried collapsing to the `_id`, but I cannot favor the `customer-index` document.

I've tried aggregation, have failed there as well.  (is there a way to limit the fields returned in the aggregation?)

I've tried `indices_boost` without success.

I feel like this should be possible, but I just have failed in coming up with the correct syntax?

Comment: Alternatively, for duplicate matches, take the document where a field (`is_edited`) exists.

Answer (score 1):

### Collapse API

> I've tried collapsing to the _id, but I cannot favor the customer-index document.

You have already used it, though it seems that as you said, you cannot favor the `customer-index`.

While using [collapse API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html), you can simply favor a document based on a specific field (here `_index`) in the sort section. so please try again, while considering the sort section with `desc` or `asc` value as ordering parameter and the `_index` field as sorting field.

finally you might need to add such a below section to your collapse query:

```json
  "sort": [
    {
      "_index": { 
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
```